# How to read words from text file into array only for a particular line?

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a text file like below. I use `fscanf` to read until it sees "found", and then read everything else **in that line** into an array. This text file is just an example so I can't hard code:

```
text text some words text 
text hello text text
text text random text
world

found read1 read2 read3
don't
read any of this
```

I have the following code so far:

```
    char **arr = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    char var[3000];

    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", var) != EOF){
        if(strcmp(arr[i], "found")==0){
            while(fscanf(fp, "%s", var)!=EOF){
                if(strcmp(var, "\n")==0){
                    break;
                }
                arr = realloc(arr, (i + 1)*sizeof(*arr));
                arr[i] = malloc(strlen(var)+1);
                strcpy(arr[i++], var);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest using `fgets` to read each line and `strstr` to see if `"found "` (with the space) is the first word and then the rest of the line can be split up with `strtok` or `strsep`. Such as `while(fgets(...) != NULL) { ... }`

Comment: Please show your code attempt as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before expecting a functional code reply.

Comment: @WeatherVane updated code. still not working though, stores everything from `read1` to end of text file for some reason, rather than that line itself. do you think you could please help me with a demo using strtok? (i don't know how to use that).  Thanks

Comment: `strcmp(var, "\n")==0` never become true.

Comment: That is because `fscanf` stops scanning at any sequence of whitespace - it can't tell whether that is space or tab or newline etc. without more complex use, and many advise that `fscanf` is not a very good way to do things. Please see my first comment,

Comment: It is not "full code". It cannot be copy/pasted and compiled as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I mentioned earlier. Perhaps you would have fewer problems if you took the time to follow up references, in general. There are plenty of example uses, and SO questions about `strtok`. If you want to proceed in coding, you *must* be proactive in your enquiries.

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/ChLloz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text looks exactly as you described then you could try:

```
char *array[100];
i = 0;

while(fscanf(file, "%s", var) != EOF){
    if(strcmp(var, "found") == 0){
        while(fscanf(file, "%s", var) != EOF){
            if( strcmp(var, "\n") == 0 ) break;
            array[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(var)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(array[i],var);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The above code is not able to stop at newline since `scanf` ignore whitespaces. In order to fix it you could use `fgets()`:

```
while(fgets(var, 3000, stdin) != NULL){
    char *checker = strstr(var, "found");
    if(checker == var){
        size_t ln = strlen(var), start = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j< ln; j++)
            if(var[j] == ' ' || var[j] == '\n'){  
                array[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(var)*sizeof(char));
                strncpy(array[i++], var + start, j - start);
                start = j;
                while(var[j++] == ' ') start ++;
            }  
    }
}
```

The above code is tested to work, just notice that it also keeps word "found" in `array[0]`. Also tested it with `stdin` but you won't have any problem replacing `stdin` with your file in `fgets(var, 3000, stdin)`.

Comment: Hi @coder! unfortunately the text doesn't have fixed properties

Comment: Yes but the line `found read1 read2 read3` is exactly as described?? the rest doesn't matter, also this line appears only one time and you only need three words (or generally a fixed number of words to store)??

Comment: I saw the edit , do you know how many words at most are in this line?? in order to know the size of the array...

Comment: there could be any number of words in the line and any name. but apart from that yes

Comment: hmm, it's giving me a segmentation fault and error regarding the EOF `int      strcmp(const char *__s1, const char *__s2);`

Comment: how is var declared?? also is the error reports anything else post it...

Comment: `warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to
      parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
                                while(strcmp(string, EOF) && strcmp(string, "\n")){` with error at EOF.

Comment: var is declared as `char var[3000];`

Comment: It's copying everything from "read1" to end of file. Pretty sure I tried this as well, before asking the question here :/

Comment: As in, I tried `if(strcmp(string, "\n")==0){` logic

Comment: Can you post full code i order to test it since till now haven't test it...

Comment: @novice, edited the answer in order to work if multiple blank spaces occur between words e.g `found read1           read2...` (still `array[0]` has word found also removed `puts(array[i])` so if you want to print don't forget to place it`).

Comment: @novice, glad to help!!